# How Spring passes instance of WebApplicationContext to DispatcherServlet constructor?

Tags: java, spring

Is anybody know how Spring loads DispatcherServlet and passes WebApplicationContext instance to DispatcherServlet constructor? Where that magic happens specifically?

Comment: That happens through `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: I can't find where it's happens specifically? In which line?

Comment: Google for it. It is generally registered in `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohit Jain is right:

`org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader` line 330ff.

```
protected WebApplicationContext createWebApplicationContext(ServletContext sc) {
    Class<?> contextClass = determineContextClass(sc);
    if (!ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.class.isAssignableFrom(contextClass)) {
        throw new ApplicationContextException("Custom context class [" + contextClass.getName() +
                "] is not of type [" + ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.class.getName() + "]");
    }
    ConfigurableWebApplicationContext wac =
            (ConfigurableWebApplicationContext) BeanUtils.instantiateClass(contextClass);
    return wac;
}
```

invoked by `public WebApplicationContext initWebApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext)` and this is invoked by `ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)`

Comment: But where is Spring instantiate DispatcherServlet?

Comment: The DispatcherServlet SERVLET itselve is created by the Web Application Container (Tomcat). It is defined in the web.xml